# Remove line break if line does not start with KEYWORD

Tags: ruby, regex, powershell, sed, awk

I have a flat file with lines that look like

```
KEYWORD|DATA STRING HERE|32|50135|ANOTHER DATA STRING
KEYWORD|STRING OF DATA|1333|552555666|ANOTHER STRING
KEYWORD|STRING OF MORE DATA|4522452|5345245245|REALLY REALLY REALLY REALLY
LONGSTRING THAT INSERTED A LINE BREAK WHEN I WAS EXTRACTING FROM SQLPLUS/ORACLE
KEYWORD|.....
```

How do I go about removing the linebreak so that

```
KEYWORD|STRING OF MORE DATA|4522452|5345245245|REALLY REALLY REALLY REALLY
LONGSTRING THAT INSERTED A LINE BREAK WHEN I WAS EXTRACTING FROM SQLPLUS/ORACLE
```

turns into

```
KEYWORD|STRING OF MORE DATA|4522452|5345245245|REALLY REALLY REALLY REALLY LONGSTRING THAT INSERTED A LINE BREAK WHEN I WAS EXTRACTING FROM SQLPLUS/ORACLE
```

This is in a HP-UNIX environment and I can move the file to another system (windows box with powershell and ruby installed).

Comment: Can you do `egrep -v "^KEYWORD" your_file.txt`?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what tools are you using, but you can use this regex to match every `\n` (or maybe `\r`) that isn't followed by `KEYWORD` so you can replace it for `SPACE` and you would have it.

[DEMO](http://regexr.com?32ure)

Regex: `\r(?!KEYWORD)` (With global modifier)

Comment: I am copying it over to a windows machine and will attempt to use that regex to replace it with notepad++ or ruby depending. Thanks.

Comment: You can even use the page I gave you with demo to replace if isn't a too long file.

Answer (score 2):

Ruby's Array has a nice method called [`slice_before`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-slice_before) that it inherits from Enumerable, which comes to the rescue here:

```
require 'pp'

text = 'KEYWORD|DATA STRING HERE|32|50135|ANOTHER DATA STRING
KEYWORD|STRING OF DATA|1333|552555666|ANOTHER STRING
KEYWORD|STRING OF MORE DATA|4522452|5345245245|REALLY REALLY REALLY REALLY
LONGSTRING THAT INSERTED A LINE BREAK WHEN I WAS EXTRACTING FROM SQLPLUS/ORACLE
KEYWORD|.....'

pp text.split("\n").slice_before(/^KEYWORD/).map{ |a| a.join(' ') }

=> ["KEYWORD|DATA STRING HERE|32|50135|ANOTHER DATA STRING",
 "KEYWORD|STRING OF DATA|1333|552555666|ANOTHER STRING",
 "KEYWORD|STRING OF MORE DATA|4522452|5345245245|REALLY REALLY REALLY REALLY LONGSTRING THAT INSERTED A LINE BREAK WHEN I WAS EXTRACTING FROM SQLPLUS/ORACLE",
 "KEYWORD|....."]
```

This code just splits your text on line breaks, then uses `slice_before` to break the resulting array into sub-arrays, one for each block of text starting with `/^KEYWORD/`. Then it walks through the resulting sub-arrays, joining them with a single space. Any line that wasn't pre-split will be left alone. Ones that were broken are rejoined.

For real use you'd probably want to replace `pp` with a regular `puts`.

As for moving the code to Windows with Ruby, why? Install Ruby on HP-Unix and run it there. It's a more natural fit.

Answer (score 1):

this short awk oneliner should do the job:

```
awk '/^KEYWORD/{print ""}{printf $0}' file
```

Comment: +1 for the solution (almost). printf $0 will mess up badly if $0 contains printf formatting characters. The synposis for printf is `printf format,data` so use it that way: `printf "%s",$0`. You also need to add an `END{print ""}`.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed ':a;$!{N;/\n.*|/!{s/\n/ /;ba}};P;D' file
```

Keep two lines in the pattern space and if the second line doesn't contain a `|` replace the newline with a space and repeat until it does or the the end of the file is reached.

This assumes the last field is the field that overflows, otherwise use the `KEYWORD` such:

```
sed ':a;$!{N;/\nKEYWORD/!{s/\n/ /;ba}};P;D' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Powershell way:

```
[System.IO.File]::ReadAllText( "c:\myfile.txt" ) -replace "`r`n(?!KEYWORD)", ' '
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sed` or `awk` (preferred) for this »

- `sed -n 's|\r||g;$!{1{x;d};H};${H;x;s|\n\(KEYWORD\)|\r\1|g;`
  `s|\n||g;s|\r|\n|g;p}' file.txt`
- `awk 'BEGIN{ORS="";}NR==1{print;next;}/^KEYWORD/`
  `{print"\n";print;next;}{print;}' file.txt`

---

***Note:*** *Write each command (`sed`, `awk`) in one line*

Comment: Ah, the clarity of a sed script :-). sed is an excellent tool for simple substitutions on a single line, for anything else, just use awk.

Comment: Just doesn't seem worthwhile posting the sed one since no-one should ever do that.

Comment: @EdMorton - I have included `sed` solution in my answer because question is tagged with `sed` as well.

Comment: Ah got it. My impression is the tools mentioned in the tags are the ones the OP thinks might solve his problem, not that he's looking for solutions in all of them but I see where you're coming from, thanks.